# How to clean up Sent Mail

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, gmail-archive

I want to keep my Sent Mail folder (label would be more correct) clean, i.e. move done messages to some archive and keep only a few that remind me of something.
In the inbox I can do this by archiving an email. It is gone from the inbox but not deleted altogether. In the Sent Mail folder this doesn't work: when I archive a sent email the Sent Mail folder keeps listing it.

Comment: I think I might have figured it out! Please check out my post on the GMail Support Forums:
https://support.google.com/mail/thread/9578278?msgid=9578278 I have also posted this on Apple Support Forums:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250474579 Let me know if this works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, Sent mail in Gmail isn't a folder nor a label. It's a system view similar to "All Mail".

The only way to remove messages from there is by deleting them.

---

**Remarks**  (Update)
As [@user829755 found](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/84149/88163) some web pages suggests the use of IMAP client to remove messages from the `Sent`. According to bkc56 in [Managing Sent Mail](http://gmail-tips.blogspot.mx/2013/05/managing-sent-mail.html) this could work temporarily but once Gmail refreshes the user mailbox index, the removed messages will appear in `Sent` again.

---

**References**
[How can I clear Sent Folder. I have assigned emails to Labels. If I delete them out of Sent Mail it will delete all. - Gmail Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/vruN4kHGJgQ)

Answer (score 0):

Rubén's answer sounds reasonable but then I found
[this URL](http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/How-To-Delete-An-Email-From-Gmail-Sent-Mail-But-Keep-A-Copy-In-All-Mail.htm) which describes how to solve the problem via the imap interface with external email client. I tried it out and it seems to work. I have now emails that I wrote myself and they appear in All Mail and under some label I gave to them but no longer in the Sent Mail folder.

**But:** see Rubén's comment

Comment: According to http://gmail-tips.blogspot.mx/2013/05/managing-sent-mail.html using IMAP to remove messages from Sent isn't permanent.

Answer (score 0):

For many years I have been using a desktop IMAP client (Microsoft Outlook) to move messages out of the Sent pseudo-folder to the Inbox.

From there I move them to the folder(s) I want them to be in. They have **never** re-appeared under Sent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a creative solution I have just started using.  I created labels sent2016, sent2015, sent2014, etc.  Then I applied the labels, for example search for sent emails `before:2016/01/01 after:2014/12/31`, select all, then click on "Select all messages that match this search", then apply the label "sent2015".  After doing this for each completed year, I then labeled all the current year's sent messages too (sent2016).

The next step, for me, since I read my email in Thunderbird, was to unsubscribe the Sent folder, and to subscribe to sent2016 instead.  Now when I look at messages in sent2016, I'm only looking at the current year, not 8 years worth of messages!

I think this would also be somewhat helpful if I were reading my gmail in the browser, too, because instead of checking the "Sent" box, I could look in the "sent2016" label.

(I did select all the old sent messages labeled "sent2015", for example, and hit "archive"; but I don't know that that was particularly helpful....)

P.S. I also unchecked IMAP for the old labels.

Comment: Bad idea, apparently.  Thunderbird keeps spinning around and around, trying to put a copy of every recently sent message.

Comment: Found http://gmail-tips.blogspot.com/2013/05/managing-sent-mail.html, have applied these suggestions: (1) hide "sent" in imap (gmail settings - > labels); show "sent2016" instead; (2) go into account settings in thunderbird, uncheck "when sending messages, automatically".